# Run command on startup only after a certain time in day

Tags: command-line, startup-applications

I want to put into startup applications a command that will check from the system time on whether it is more than i.e. 17:00 hours and then depending on the result the command would execute another command.

Is that possible?

Comment: That is just a normal crontab rule. See /etc/crontab. If you want it executed at 17:00 use that. You can also have it run after 17:00 and then every so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that will check to see if it is after 17:00 then perform a task of turning the backlight on.

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date +%k%M)

if [[ "$time" -ge 1700 ]];then
    echo "Backlight on"
    xset led 3
else
    echo "Backlight off"
    xset -led 3
fi
```

On a 24 hour clock, midnight `0:00` would be less than `17:00` so it would then become `false` and not run.

Or, if you want, anytime after `17:00` but before `08:00` could look like this as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date +%k%M)

if [[ "$time" -ge 1700 || "$time" -le 759 ]];then
    echo "Backlight on"
    xset led 3
else
    echo "Backlight off"
    xset -led 3
fi
```

You could also add a `cron` job under root settings so all users will have it run twice a day, once at 17:00, the other at 08:00 in case the system is on during these times:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

add the following at the bottom of the cron file:

```
00 08,17 * * * /path/to/script_file
```

Comment: I want to run the command "xset led 3" if it is after 17:00 when I boot up.If it is not I want nothing to happen.

Comment: @MarioKamenjak I just updated the script.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @MarioKamenjak I added a turn off for after 0:00 midnight.

Comment: THX.
I have modified it to this:
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date +%k%M)

if [[ "$time" -ge 1700 ]];then
    xset led 3
    echo "backlight on"
else
    xset -led 3
    echo "backlight not on"
fi

Comment: @MarioKamenjak I made the modifications here as well for you.